# Backbone.js - Parsing the complex json data response from the server and adding it to collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I need to parse json data and using backbone.js need to add it to a collection.

This is the json data which i'm getting from the server:

```
{"name":"mail","server":[{"name":"1","port":"8080","domain":"mail"},{"name":"2","port":"8080","domain":"mail"},{"name":"3","port":"8080","domain":"mail"},{"name":"4","port":"8080","domain":"mail"},"count":4}
```

The following is the java script code which i'm using to access json data from server. Before I display it using datatables.js I need to add the json data to backbone collections and then display it using datatable.js.

```
$(function(){

$('#okbtn').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax(
    {

        type:"GET",
        url:"/LoginWebService/Domain",

        success:Response
    });
});
});

function Response(result)
{

if(result!="[]")
    {

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bLengthchange":false,
        "bFilter":false,
        "bSort":true,
        "bIntro":false,
        "bAutoWidth":false,
        "bProcessing": true,
         "aaData":result, 
        "aoColumns": [
                          { "mData": "name" },
                          { "mData": "port" },
                          { "mData": "dom" }
                      ],
        "bJQueryUI":true
    } );


    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Padfoot, and welcome to Stack Overflow! It is not clear what your question is, so please improve your chances of getting good answers by telling us what you want to achieve, what you've already tried, and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some tutorials which helped me a lot:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/get-connected-to-the-backbone-new-course/?search_index=5

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

Wish you good luck!

Comment: You can add some information about what you have heard in the video.  So add details to your answer.